# Add transition to a div when displaces

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I'm wondering is it possible to add transition to html elements displacement?
To explain it, assume there is an alert box (I'm using Bootstrap) and when user clicks that little 'x' to dismiss it, other elements those are located below the alert box, move up roughly.
[image]

This is just a sample form. I want to make this movement smoothly, if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('body').on('click','.somethinghashappened', function(e) {
    $(this).fadeOut(500,function(){
        $(this).css({"visibility":"hidden",display:'block'}).slideUp();
    });
});`

It fadeouts then alert block sets to display block, and it slides that(alert) block up, which cause to slide your div up.//

http://jsfiddle.net/kMxqj/17/

You can check this fiddle, some other goot person already did that! :)
[Create smooth transition of block elements when removing sibling elements from DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366510/create-smooth-transition-of-block-elements-when-removing-sibling-elements-from-d)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you're using jquery animation functions (slideUp maybe) for this.

Jquery animates the height of the element to 0 and then add `display: none` css property, but the padding of the element is not animated, so if it's not 0 when the element is hidden there is a jump in the elements below.

You can put the element inside a wrapper, and animate it, or just **use css animations**.